# Forgot Password - Success Message/Flash Message after setting new password on the login screen

Tags: form, password

Quick question about password reset (forgot a password on the front-end)

So I have set my
`'setPasswordSuccessPath'           => 'login'`
so that when the new password is set, they will be taken to this login screen.

Is there anyway i can detect this has come from this process, so I can show a little flash message to confirm their password has been reset? I'd like to give some visual feedback, without a whole separate interim page.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is by simply `include`ing the same template as the login page and passing a Twig variable along with it.

So more specifically, my `setPasswordSuccessPath` is set to a unique template called `password-was-reset`, which has the following code in it and nothing else:

`{% include 'login' with { passwordWasReset: true } %}`

You can then read that variable in your login template like this - as you can see I'm also doing the same thing with my account activation template:

```
    {% if passwordWasReset is defined and passwordWasReset and errorMessage is not defined %}       
        <p>Your password was reset successfully. Please login below.</p>        
    {% endif %}

    {% if accountWasActivated is defined and accountWasActivated and errorMessage is not defined %}
        <p>Your account was activated successfully. Please login below.</p>
    {% endif %}

    ...

    <login form here>
```